# Copying files from one server to another using SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, copy, agent

I have a job which that runs weekly as maintenance work and takes backup of the databases. After maintenance, I have to take copy of databases after specified time to local disk and to a location to remote server.

I have created a batch file to copy files to local and remote location. The local copy works fine and the files are copied, but for the remote location, in the job history it says successful but when checked on remote location, the files weren't copied.

I have tried to call task scheduler from SQL Server which it does but still files are not copied on the remote location. Please help me out with this.

Comment: does the account that the sql agent service run under, have access to the UNC share?

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, it has. But I don't want SQL Agent to be privileged. I want some other method to do it. Help me out with this context.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?